# Codility - FrogRiverOne - Swift

Tags: swift

I am trying to find an optimal swift solution for the below codility task, Please do share your views.

Time Complexity - O(N**2)

**TASK DESCRIPTION**

A small frog wants to get to the other side of a river. The frog is initially located on one bank of the river (position 0) and wants to get to the opposite bank (position X+1). Leaves fall from a tree onto the surface of the river.

You are given an array A consisting of N integers representing the falling leaves. A[K] represents the position where one leaf falls at time K, measured in seconds.

The goal is to find the earliest time when the frog can jump to the other side of the river. The frog can cross only when leaves appear at every position across the river from 1 to X (that is, we want to find the earliest moment when all the positions from 1 to X are covered by leaves). You may assume that the speed of the current in the river is negligibly small, i.e. the leaves do not change their positions once they fall in the river.

For example, you are given integer X = 5 and array A such that:

```
A[0] = 1
A[1] = 3
A[2] = 1
A[3] = 4
A[4] = 2
A[5] = 3
A[6] = 5
A[7] = 4
```

In second 6, a leaf falls into position 5. This is the earliest time when leaves appear in every position across the river.

Write a function:

```
public func solution(_ X : Int, _ A : inout [Int]) -> Int
```

that, given a non-empty array A consisting of N integers and integer X, returns the earliest time when the frog can jump to the other side of the river.

If the frog is never able to jump to the other side of the river, the function should return −1.

For example, given X = 5 and array A such that:

```
A[0] = 1
A[1] = 3
A[2] = 1
A[3] = 4
A[4] = 2
A[5] = 3
A[6] = 5
A[7] = 4
```

the function should return 6, as explained above.

Write an efficient algorithm for the following assumptions:

> N and X are integers within the range [1..100,000]; each element of
> array A is an integer within the range [1..X].

## Edit - Missed adding my approach, thanks for highlighting it, really appreciate your time. Namaste

```
public func solution(_ X : Int, _ A : inout [Int]) -> Int {
    // write your code in Swift 4.2.1 (Linux)
    let destination  = X
    var positionDict = [Int: Bool]()
        
    for (index,value) in A.enumerated() {
        if value <= destination, positionDict[value] == nil  {
            positionDict[value] = true
        }
        if hasPositions(initial: A[0], destination: X, dict: positionDict) {
            return index
        }
    }
    return -1
}

func hasPositions(initial: Int, destination: Int, dict: [Int: Bool]) -> Bool {
    for i in stride(from: initial, to: destination+1, by: 1 ) {
        if dict[i] == nil {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}

var arr = [1,3,1,4,2,3,5,4]
print(solution(5, &arr))

//CODILITY gave 45 % for the solution, please share where am i going wrong.
```

Comment: This exercise is not Swifty at all. Tell them to rewrite it.

Comment: "I am trying to find…", by having someone else do the work for you? Add your own attempt at solving this and explain what issue you are facing and we can perhaps help you with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```swift
public func solution(_ X : Int, _ A : inout [Int]) -> Int {
  typealias  = [Int]
  typealias  = EnumeratedSequence<>
  let  = .first
  let  = 1
  var  = Set(...X)

  return try!
    (A.enumerated()) ({
        .remove($0.element)
        return .isEmpty
      })?
      .offset
    ?? -
}
```